# php algorithm to divide and set numbers

Tags: php, algorithm, pagination, cursor

I have an array which could be of any size coming from users.

The maximum size of values in each request to the API is 100 (from 0 - 99), a user **could have ( it varies could be 64 or 137 or .... )**  234 values in his own array, what I want is to get the first hundred values, the next 100 values, then the next 34 values stored in an array or a string.

Something like ;

```
First Hundred   : 0 - 99    //100
Second Hundred  : 100 - 199 //100  
Next Values     : 200 - 234 //34
```

In each instance the values get appended to a string as seen below.

```
  $lookupString = "";

  //$notfm = one-dim array of values

  for( $i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++ ){
         $lookupString .= $notfm[$i].",";
    }

 $lookup = "http://api.lol.com/1/?user_ids=".$lookupString;
```

Can someone help me on this? I think this is easy but I'm missing something. Thanks.

Sample of the json encoded array can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/fHBA6d4t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the array_chunk function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$request_bits = array_chunk($notfm, 100)

foreach ($request_bits as $request_bit) {
    ...
}
```

Alternately, you can set a separate condition to make the request when the counter is 100, empty the array of IDs, and empty the counter, but unless memory management is a huge issue array_chunk will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$input_array;

// Split into chunks of 100
$chunks = array_chunk($input_array, 100);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
{
  // Build the lookup string
  $lookupString = implode(",", $chunk);

  // DO LOOKUP HERE
}
```

Whenever I need to work with arrays, I open up the [array functions manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). A quick scan through the descriptions can often point you to an array function that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get familiar with `range()` and `array_chunk()`:

```
// make an array with all the numbers from 1 to 1000
$notfm = range(1,1000);

// make groups of 100 each
$chunks = array_chunk($notfm, 100);

// loop over each chunk of 100
foreach ($chunks as $lookupArray) {
    $lookupString = implode(',', $lookupArray);
    $lookup = "http://api.example.com/1/?user_ids=" . rawurlencode($lookupString);
    // do stuff
}
```

Documentation: [range()](https://www.php.net/range), [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/array_chunk), [implode()](https://www.php.net/implode)

Comment: I think that he gets his array of IDs from the users already.

Comment: True, but to test it seeing it work on a range is good. I also added a `rawurlencode` code just now so if garbage gets in there the OP is not open to an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Feel free to vote up the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php)

```
$first = array_slice( $input, 0, 100 );
$second = array_slice( $input, 100, 100 );
$third = array_slice( $input, 200, 34 );
```

And after goes the way what you want.